# Can't load iguanatex64 into Powerpoint2013

Tags: powerpoint

I tried out [IguanaTeX](http://tx.technion.ac.il/~zvikabh/software/iguanatex/) with PPT 2013 under Windows 8.1 .   I initially loaded it and it worked fine on a blank presentation.  The next time I opened up PowerPoint, I got a message saying that PowerPoint had stopped working had to close down.

The third time I opened up PPT, it said that it had had difficulty with IguanaTex, and did I want to disable it?   If I disabled it, things were ok, but of course I couldn't use IguanaTex.  If I said not to disable it, I got the "PowerPoint has stopped working" message.

I'm using PowerPoint 2013 (64 bit version) on 64-bit Windows 8.1, and IguanaTex64.

Any suggestions for how to debug or solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: The problem is most likely to be caused by Kaspersky Intenet Security. It has been reported to prevent AddIns from [running](http://forum.kaspersky.com/lofiversion/index.php/t277011.html). So far there is no other solution than getting rid of Kaspersky by reimagining the system.

Comment: Have you any **proof** for your assumption?

Comment: I experienced the problem. I have tested the solution myself. This involved reimagining the system 2 times. First, with installing KIS 2014 after which the problem occurred and still persisted even after uninstalling Kaspersky. Second time I did not installed it and a problem has not occurred. By investigating the phenomenon empirically I discovered a pattern.

Unfortunately, I have not came up yet with a strict mathematical proof, but I am working on it. You can support me by donating 100 euros.